# Event Handler in JavaFX suddenly stops working

Tags: java, events, javafx, freeze

I have a simple JavaFX program that moves a shape. The movement is controlled by keys and the options to move are left, right and jump. The program runs normally except that sometimes the event handler just goes dead. The only consistency I've found so far is that it happens only after a left movement, but I can't see any patterns as to *when* it happens.

What could case this kind of behaviour? Is my code broken?

**UPDATE:** I replaced `shape.requestFocus();` with `shape.setFocusTraversable(true);` and it helped a little: Now I can move the shape to the right after it freezes, but not to the left. Also if I move it to the left after "unfreezing" it I can perform a jump. Moving left will freeze the shape again.

NOTE: The shape is a `Rectangle shape = new Rectangle();`

Handler:

```
shape.setFocusTraversable(true);
shape.setOnKeyPress((e) -> {
    if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
        shape.moveRight();
    }
    else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
        shape.moveLeft();
    }
    else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        shape.jump();
    }
});
```

Methods for moving:

```
public void moveLeft() {
    shape.setX(shape.getX() - 3);
}

public void moveRight() {
    shape.setX(shape.getX() + 3);
}

public void jump() {
    Arc path = new Arc();
    path.setCenterX(shape.getX() + shape.getWidth() / 2 + 20);
    path.setCenterY(shape.getY() + shape.getHeight() / 2);
    path.setRadiusX(40);
    path.setRadiusY(80);
    path.setStartAngle(180);
    path.setLength(-180);

    PathTransition jump = new PathTransition();
    jump.setPath(path);
    jump.setNode(shape);
    jump.setDuration(Duration.millis(1500));
    jump.play();
    shape.setX(path.getCenterX() + path.getRadiusX() + 15);
}
```

Comment: A key event handler is only fired if the node has keyboard focus, so I assume you must be calling `shape.setFocusTraversable(true);` somewhere. Is it just losing keyboard focus somehow?

Comment: Replaced `shape.requestFocus()` with `shape.setFocusTraversable(true);`and it helped somewhat but the problem it still there. See the post for update.